# cannot convert `int*' to `float*' for argument `1' to `float mean(float*, float)'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

float mean (float num[], float n)
{
    int i;
    float sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    sum=sum+num[i];
    return (sum/n);

}
int main()  
{

    int minusElements;  
    int n;
    cout << "Enter number of Elements:";  
    cin >> n;



    minusElements = n - 1  ;
    int i,j, num[n];  
    float  temp;

    float f;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
    {
    cin >> f;
    num.push_back(f);
    }


    cout << "Enter " << n << " numbers:\n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
    cin >> num[i];
    cin.get();
    float m = mean(&num[0], num.size());


}  

//33 request for member `push_back' in `num', which is of non-class type `int[((unsigned int)((int)n))]' 

//41 request for member `size' in `num', which is of non-class type `int[((unsigned int)((int)n))]'
```

Comment: Please indent your code (it's more likely to make people want to answer), and also include the following things in the body: what the goal of this code is, what you've tried, and what's not working.

Comment: I see uninitialized variables in `mean`.

Comment: @Chris I fixed the code indentation, but in doing so I discovered a big nesting of code (like `for` loops) without `{ }` surrounding braces, which made it very difficult for me to ascertain what was intentionally nested code and what wasnt. John: if you could please add `{ }` braces so we know what code should be nested and what code shouldnt be.

Answer (score 5):

First thing first:

```
 int num[numElements];
```

This is not allowed in Standard C++. Its variable length array (VLA) since `numElements` is not a `const` expression. VLA is allowed only in C99.

---

```
cout << "Mean:"<< mean(num,n);
```

`mean()` takes `float*` but type of `num` is `int[]` which can convert to `int*`, but not to `float*`. Hence the error.

The solution is : in C++, use `std::vector<float>` as:

```
#include <vector> //must include this!

std::vector<float> num;

float f;
for(i=0;i<numElements;i++)  
{
  cin >> f;
  num.push_back(f);
}

//then call mean() as
float m = mean(&num[0], num.size());
```

Beside all these, your `mean()` function is wrongly implemented. What is `numElements`? Its an uninitialized variable which you're using in the `for` loop. This invokes undefined-behaviour. Solution is : you don't need `numElements` to begin with. Just use `n` which you pass to the function as argument.

---

Also, in C++, you don't even need a function to calculate the mean, you can use functions from `<numeric>` as:

```
#include <numeric>

//if num is std::vector
float mean = std::accumulate(num.begin(), num.end(), 0) / num.size();

//if num is float[n] or float* (num of elements = n)
float mean = std::accumulate(num, num + n, 0) / n;
```

---

Alright. Since you're a beginner and wants to learn how to solve this problem. After you tried yourself which didn't work, so here is how you should be doing this:

### C-style coding in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

float mean (float *num, int n)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
          sum += num[i];
    return sum/n; 
}
int main()  
{
    int count; 
    std::cin >> count;
    float *numbers = new float[count]; //allocate memory!

    for(int i=0; i< count ;i++)  
    {
       std::cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    std::cout << mean(numbers, count) << std::endl;
    delete [] numbers; //must deallocate the memory!
}
```

Input (number of elements followed by the elements on the next line):

```
6
12 89 23 12 32 11
```

Output:

```
29.8333
```

Online Demo : http://www.ideone.com/hdZPd

Note C-style coding in C++ is not recommended, but its okay for learning purpose only.

---

### C++ style coding in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main()  
{
    int count; 
    std::cin >> count;
    std::vector<float> numbers(count);

    for(int i=0; i< count ;i++)  
    {
       std::cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    float mean = std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.0)/ numbers.size();
    std::cout << mean << std::endl;
}
```

Input (number of elements followed by the elements on the next line):

```
6
12 89 23 12 32 11
```

Output:

```
29.8333
```

Online Demo : http://www.ideone.com/aZ7u8

Hope it helps you understanding the problem and the solution in both style.

Comment: He's probably using one where it allows you to do so, from the title you can see he has an issue with passing an int array to a function that wants a float array. Although he should fix his question....

Comment: I'm just a newbie in C++

Comment: @John: No problem. You will learn C++ gradually. In this case, you don't even need `mean()` function. See my answer again. I explained how you can use `std::accumulate` function from `<numeric>` header.

Comment: @Nawaz: Sir, can we start at the beginning?

Comment: @Nawaz: On Making function for the mean. I really don't understand. If its okay with you sir?

Comment: @John: I think its homework. So I cannot help with the implementation of `mean` function. You need to struggle a bit more. Its very easy to implement. Did you replaced `numElements` with `n` in the `mean` function as I suggested?

Comment: @Nawaz: nope Sir. I make the mean but I put the Element only 10 so put on num[1], num[2], etc. But now, i want the user will input the element.

Comment: @Als: Oops. I meant `First thing first` :P

Comment: @John: See the solutions now. You should be ultimately learning C++ style coding.

Comment: @Nawaz: okay sir! thanks for the help me understanding. i will study that one

Comment: @Nawaz: Sir, could you let me understand the meaning of this statement please. -std::cin >> count;
                  -float *numbers = new float[count]

Comment: @John: Get a good book. You need one. Seriously. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: Okay Sir. I will buy one if I can afford. We don't have books in our school. Only teacher discuss, but I can't understand some of his codes.

Comment: @Nawaz: Sir, wat if code using function sir? without using the numeric?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the title to this question, I'm fairly certain your problem is with this line:

```
int num[numElements], i,j,temp;
```

You meant:

```
int i,j;
// shouldn't be using num[numElements] in c++ (see Nawaz's answer for why)
float num[], temp; // temp *also* should be a fload based on usage.
```

You also seem to have an extra `for(i=0;i<numElements;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Change int num[numElements] to float num[numElements]? You're sending an array of ints to something that expects an array of floats.